# Porque tá retornando esse erro?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou utilizando o plugin [jQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net/) e comecei a fazer a ativação server-side

mas ao carregar ele informa um alert:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Seguindo eu fiz o debug, e no último passo, em que é para mostrar o JSON com os dados, aparece: *This request has no response data available.*

Porque esse erro ainda está ocorrendo? PoQUE reSposta Invalida do JSON, o que está invalido????????

A página com a tabela **html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",

        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    } );
} );

</script>
```

E o **server_processing.php**:

```
<?php
$table = 'tbl_medic';
$primaryKey = 'id_Medic';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'nome', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cidade',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cep',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'crm',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'pastaDocumentos',     'dt' => 5 )
);

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '***', //Usuário do banco de dados
    'pass' => '***', //Senha do banco de dados
    'db'   => '***', //Banco de dados
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require_once( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!!

Tente forçar o array para object da seguinte maneira:

```
$columns = (object) array(
    array( 'db' => 'nome', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cidade',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cep',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'crm',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'pastaDocumentos',     'dt' => 5 )
);
```